Improve upload error message for animated WebP images
Animated WebP images are not supported. The error message is misleading (test file):

Not a valid file type: please upload a bmp, gif, jpeg, png, or webp file.

Feature request: Improve upload error message for animated WebP images, e.g.:

Animated WebP images are not supported.


(Note that animated PNGs work fine, e.g. https://i.sstatic.net/EXLLfEZP.png)

It would probably be easier to change webp to non-animated webp in the original message.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk works too

Or static webp to save a few bytes (I used to do some challenges in CodeGolf.SE)

Well they currently just doesn't really check for such a thing, most likely - so this SO question might help.

PNGs can also be animated, whatever minigation is implemented it should be implemented for animated PNGs too

@mousetail animated PNGs work fine eg https://i.sstatic.net/EXLLfEZP.png

Why not just support animated webp? That's sort of what they are for...

Requested support for animated WebP images here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402470/could-we-support-animated-webp-images

@JohanWalles thanks, even better indeed!

Just linking to yet another example (closed as a duplicate, which is valid) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404845

Another suggestion which is more simple to implement and will also make it more clear, is change the existing message to this instead:

Not a valid file type: please upload a bmp, gif, jpeg, png, or a non-animated webp file.

