Uploading a WebP file ends up with error: "Not a valid file type: please upload a bmp, gif, jpeg, png, or webp file."
On meta.stackexchange.com, like I'm posting this now, uploading a WebP file seems to work.
But on blender.stackexchange.com, posting the same WebP file results in an error with the following message.:

Not a valid file type: please upload a bmp, gif, jpeg, png, or webp file.


A bit more of the detail of the file in question:
$ file aa.webp 
aa.webp: RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image

I've been unable to find the local rule on Blender's community so asking here, but please feel free to redirect to a better place if any.

UPDATE: After posting this question I noticed the .webp file I pasted above is converted to a .png file and not acting as a webp animation. While I'm not yet familiar whether that conversion of webp to png is an expected behavior, the behavior on blender community described above needs to be explained, and the error message doesn't make sense IMO.
UPDATE-2: Original webp file can be obtained on my online storage.
UPDATE-3: In order to verify the reproducibility, I now tried uploading the same animated .webp file in question on meta site, I too get the expected error. I said earlier above that I was able to upload the file w/o error, which I still think is true, but now I can't reproduce that. To verify I've really used an animated .webp file (instead of a static image), I looked into my filesystem. I do not have a static image version of the .webp file; Other than the .webp, I have .webm that I used to generate .webp. That kind of backs me up that I did NOT upload a static image file when I said there was error occurred.

Can you please link to the original webp file (hosted somewhere else), so that we can try and reproduce? Trying to upload the test file here shows the error you mention and does not convert it to a .png file.

@ShadowWizard Thanks for asking, I included a link to the file in the update-2.

Well tried to upload it here and as expected, it's not possible because it's animated. You wrote you were able to upload a .webp image here but not on blender site, that is a different and more severe bug if it can be reproduced. So what image exactly were you able to upload here, and not there?
